# unicode_literals everywhere in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

Is there a way to get the behaviour of

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

to apply project-wide, apart from putting this import in the top of each and every module?

I would like to just define it in one place, like the `__init__.py` of the package directory of project root say, and have it recursively apply to subpackages and submodules.

Comment: `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`, you need to modify a python lib for this to work tho because the default behavior of Python is `del sys.setdefaultencoding`.. I usually remove it, doesn't cause any issues and it gives me a lot of freedom to do weird shit :)

Comment: No, I don't want to change all the semantics of IO and break the environment just for this.  I only want to change what a string literal means in source code.

Comment: I will have default encoding 'ascii' and put `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in source files, when needed.  But I want 'strings' _without_ the u prefix to be parsed to unicode rather than bytes.

Comment: I guess it would be possible to write some kind of import hook that detected particular submodule paths and monkeyed with the import's code object compile step to include extra future flags. Definitely not worth the bother though!

Comment: The closest thing Python provides is documented under ["Options you shouldn't use"](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#options-you-shouldn-t-use), and it turns on `unicode_literals` *everywhere* everywhere, including in the standard library and in other libraries you have installed, not just in your own project's code. Direct docs quote: "Do not be tempted to use this option as it will probably break your world."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR - No

Command-line option **`-U`** enables unicode globally.  From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#id4):

> Turns all string literals into unicodes globally. Do not be tempted to use this option as it will probably break your world. It also produces `.pyc` files with a different magic number than normal.

You can't use it in practice, though, because it will mess up even the standard library. The docs advise just to enable unicode literals on a per-module basis using the future import.